# Field Research Error And It Goes Blank

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

So this happen when i was claim a field research reward of catching 10 pokemon, and then Ghastly appeared.

Im not catching him immediately coz ran out of pokeballs and save this rewards for later. But when i want to take the reward, the capture screen it become a blank.

[image: error1]

And also the field research become 4 column @@

[image: 4column]

Anyone got an idea what should i do ?

Comment: Despite this being duplicate, the OP deserves a quick response. This is a known bug that Niantic is working on. Normally it's caused because you fed the pokemon a berry before running away. There is no timeline for when this bug will be fixed, but there have been updates in the time since this was posted, so it may be fixed. If it is not, the only solution at this point is to close and restart the app. You will not be able to try to catch the pokemon until the bug is fixed.

Comment: To add to @Kadima's response, there is a fix deployed on Android, but not yet for IOS. updating the game now should fix it.